# How to stop exit code one from popping up in my console?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator in python. The whole idea is that I can integrate multiple types of calculators inside one big one. Right now I am trying to put both geometry and basic numbers into my calculators. Here is the code:

```
    #varibles
question = input("do you want shapes or numbers: ")

if question == "shapes":
    geometry = input("This is for shapes. Enter which shape: triangle and rectangle: ")

    # normal
    if geometry == "triangle":
        base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
        height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
        print((base * height) / 2)
    elif geometry == "rectangle":
        number1 = int(input("Enter length: "))
        number2 = int(input("Enter width: "))
        print(number1 * number2)

    else:
        print("invalid operation. please restart the program and try again")

if question == "numbers":
    operation = input("Enter the operation. * for multiply. / for divide. + for add. - for subtract. ^ for power of: ")
    number1: int = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    number2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

#normal
if operation == "+":
    # print(int(number1) * int(number2))
    print(number1 + number2)
if operation == "-":
    print(number1 - number2)
elif operation == "*":
    print(number1 * number2)
elif operation == "/":
    print(number1 / number2)
elif operation == "^":
    print(pow (number1,number2))
else:
    print("invalid operation. please restart the program and try again")

#triangle
```

Whenever I run the program, it gives me this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rohit/PycharmProjects/untitled2/attempt 1.py", line 26, in <module>
    if operation == "+":
NameError: name 'operation' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix my code so I don't get this error message?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with exit codes. Rather, it is entirely due to you referencing the variable `operation` in an equality comparison before `operation` is ever assigned a value. Clearly if `question == "numbers"` is not true that `operation` never receives a value, thus it causes an error on reference.

Comment: your ```operations``` ```if...esle``` block should be inside ```if question=='numbers'``` bloack

Comment: Just search about `scope`, this thing is in most programming languages :)

Answer (score 0):

Operation only exists if question == "numbers"
So if that is false then "operation" isn't a variable that exists and so it immediately throws an error.

Comment: so how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

In the last part of the code:

```
if question == "numbers":
    operation = input("Enter the operation. * for multiply. / for divide. + for add. - for subtract. ^ for power of: ")
    number1: int = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    number2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

#normal
if operation == "+":
    # print(int(number1) * int(number2))
    print(number1 + number2)
if operation == "-":
    print(number1 - number2)
elif operation == "*":
    print(number1 * number2)
elif operation == "/":
    print(number1 / number2)
elif operation == "^":
    print(pow (number1,number2))
else:
    print("invalid operation. please restart the program and try again")
```

`operation` is defined only when the `question` equals `numbers`.
However, your if block is indented with `if question=='numbers'`. So it will be executed regardless of whether `operation` is defined or nor.

To fix it:

```
if question == "numbers":
    operation = input("Enter the operation. * for multiply. / for divide. + for add. - for subtract. ^ for power of: ")
    number1: int = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    number2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

#normal
    if operation == "+":
        # print(int(number1) * int(number2))
        print(number1 + number2)
    elif operation == "-":
        print(number1 - number2)
    elif operation == "*":
        print(number1 * number2)
    elif operation == "/":
        print(number1 / number2)
    elif operation == "^":
        print(pow (number1,number2))
    else:
        print("invalid operation. please restart the program and try again")
```

Indent the conditions inside the `if question=='numbers'`

Answer (score 0):

### Python relies on Indentation

To align blocks of code, Python differs from other programming-languages that use parentheses or curly-brackets. Python relies on indentation to mark blocks of contiguous code.
See the concept illustrated at [W3-Schools, Python If Indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_indentation.asp)
or the official [PEP-8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

### Solving your issue

As far as I understood your calculator has 2 modes:

- *shapes*: calculate the area of given a predefined shape-type
- *numbers*: calculate the result given an **operator** and 2 *numbers*

#### The Numbers part

Now let's focus on the *numbers* mode in the second part of your code:

```py
if question == "numbers":
    operation = input("Enter the operation. * for multiply. / for divide. + for add. - for subtract. ^ for power of: ")
    # the previously defined variable `operation` has local scope inside the if-block
    number1: int = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    number2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

# the following lines need to be indented to be aligned with previous

    # normal
    if operation == "+":
        print(number1 + number2)
    if operation == "-":
        print(number1 - number2)
    elif operation == "*":
        print(number1 * number2)
    elif operation == "/":
        print(number1 / number2)
    elif operation == "^":
        print(pow (number1,number2))
    else:
        print("invalid operation. please restart the program and try again")
```

You `operation` only visible inside the if-block, where it first was defined. Because your given code, e.g. erroneous statement `if operation == "+"` is outside the if-block, it does not know `operation`. You could simply indent the whole operation tests, so they are inside the if-block and `operation` becomes visible to them.

### Further Improvement

#### Inconsistent code

Why did you define the variable `number1` differently than the second?
Look how `number1: int = int(input("Enter the first number: "))` is different.

#### Basic Programming Principles

I would highly recommend to split up the two parts into separate methods/functions. This principle is called [*Single Responsibility Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Benefit is you can focus on each part separately, only a single responsibility per function.

```py
calculation_mode = input("do you want shapes or numbers: ")

if calculation_mode == "shapes":
    calculate_shapes()
elif calculation_mode == "numbers":
    calculate_numbers()
else:
    print("Can only calculate 'shapes' or 'numbers'.")

def calculate_shapes():
     # here the input and calculation specific to shapes

def calculate_numbers():
     # here the input and calculation specific to numbers
```

This will increase readability and immediately shows an edge-case that was not yet covered: user entered invalid mode (I added a warning print-out in the `else` block above).

#### Enhance further at CodeReview

To get more improvements and learn clean-code principles right from the start, post your working Python code to the sister community [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).